# Microsoft MIPS assembler

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mips

I was searching for an assembler to generate MIPS binary from asm files and stumbled upon [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253922%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Where can I find this assembler. Did not find a link to download this. I have Visual Studio 2010 installed, it doesn't show Assembler project types. Basically I need to generate MIPS binaries to test the disassembler I did as part of course work.

Comment: Apple killed that off.  All Windows Mobile development tools were removed from VS2010 and the team has been dissolved.  Not so sure if older versions of VS have it, I never came across it.  Talk to your teacher, MIPS tools are common in academia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* MIPS is supported with Windows CE. Otherwise the Gnu toolchain for MIPS is widely available. That will give you a MIPS cross-assembler and linker.

Answer (score 0):

the `MIPS` Assembler is present in `VS 2008` but not in `VS 2010`.  it is a stand alone tool and found in `%program files%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\ce\bin\x86_mips`